# Running SQL query using SignalR

Tags: c#, signalr

Most of my experience is with applications and I am having trouble working with a SQL query.
The web page uses signalr to update clients with new info which will be controlled by a different process but what I am trying to implement is that new connected clients will not be at the same place as others already joined so it will update new clients with the correct info. I have this SQL Query ,

```
 public string LoadCurrent()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();

        SqlConnectionStringBuilder bldr = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        bldr.DataSource = @"server\SQLEXPRESS";
        bldr.InitialCatalog = "Signalr_Example";
        bldr.UserID = "zip";
        bldr.Password = "zap";

        con.ConnectionString = bldr.ConnectionString;

            con.Open();

            string currentPage = "";

            using (SqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 activepage FROM active";

                con.Open();

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                SqlDataReader myReader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    int _currentpage = myReader.GetOrdinal("activepage");
                    currentPage = myReader.GetString(_currentpage);

                }

            } 

        return currentPage;

    }
```

Which I would like to return when a client connects

```
    public Task Connect()
    {
        string html = LoadCurrent();
        _connections.TryAdd(Context.ConnectionId, null);
        //This runs firstview which populates a content div on new clients. 
        Clients[Context.ConnectionId].firstview(html);
        return Clients.tally(_connections.Count.ToString());
    }
```

while this works in a winapp , it breaks all of signalr on my page when run and does not return the result. I am probably doing something I am not supposed to , so I thought I would ask.

Comment: please post the error. Are you running it under IIS or from visual studio?

Comment: There is no error, the content tries to refresh and succeeds but is always blank, normal strings work fine but so "hello world" would work, but not "hello world" + html is just empty. I have tried it both on IIS on the server and IIS express in VS2012.

Comment: i am guessing you will need to encode the html before you send it

Comment: the html at the moment is a string of "ok" and won't need encoded , just trying to get the basics working.

Answer (score 0):

command.CommandText = "SELECT activepage FROM active";

instead of

command.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 activepage FROM active";